# Good continuous-integration solutions for Haskell projects

Tags: git, haskell, continuous-integration

I am looking for a good CI solution for a haskell project. Ideally something that will work with git. Really basic need (so far) build and run tests after each check in. Some basic reporting would be great too, but it does not need to be anything real fancy. It should also support running javascript tests in a browser. (via Selenium or the like)

What have people been using for this?

Comment: You'll probably be better served by asking on reddit.com/r/programming. Those guys love haskell.

Comment: Can you script what you want to do?

Comment: I probably could have, in truth this question is no longer relevant as I decided to go with Erlang over Haskell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have first hand knowledge of these solutions applied to Haskell, but I do have a passing interest in it.

First a few SO questions that could be helpful:

1. [Lightweight Continuous Integration for a centrally Haskell/Darcs toolchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000005/lightweight-continuous-integration-for-a-centrally-haskell-darcs-toolchain)
2. [Haskell Build Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096746/haskell-build-automation)

Also you may want to look into [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) / [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (it's the same project, but forked due to some politics I'm not going to get into)... But Hudson/Jenkins is a pluggable build system that is used often in Java/Maven systems, but thanks to its many community created plugins it has support for Git, and the ability to run arbitrary sets of commands for builds. (I haven't found a Haskell plugin for it yet, but perhaps someone could create one).

Comment: Hudson/Jenkins allows you to execute any arbitrary shell script. I find it to be a lot easier than messing around with the plugins at times (which don't always install correctly).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for good CI solutions for Haskell similarly and found no really easy to use ones, so I went on to create a plugin for a CI server called TeamCity. I've imaginatively called it 'Cabal TeamCity build runner'.

Find out more at the plugin's [project webpage](http://fushunpoon.github.com/cabal-teamcity-plugin/) and at my [blog post about it](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/05/20/continuous-integration-for-haskell-cabal-teamcity-plugin).